# How can I repair foxpro .dbf database error message?

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have a client who received an error message when their Foxpro application initiated, Foxpro v9.0 error msg: "Unrecognized Database Format".

My client reported that he had a power failure and the problem appeared after he rebooted the PC.

It appears that the foxpro database corruption was caused by the power failure.

Any suggestions, friends...

Comment: "Unrecognized Database Format" does not seem to be among the native VFP9 Error Messages 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zt972hbf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx . If yours is perhaps a custom message created in the client code, it might help to know the real VFP Error Number

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a link for VFP code](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~UDFFixRecCount) to repair corrupt table headers in VFP.  Provided you have VFP, it basically does a low-level file open, checks entire file size, detects record size and resets the record count.  I have a client who still has VFP apps going, and once in a great while, they too have whatever power outage / surges / network connectivity issues and corrupts the header.  They run this routine and back in business...

Comment: That's indeed a helpful link, and I wonder why it got downvoted by someone or something

Comment: @StefanWuebbe, Yeah... me too  I hate that people down-vote without any justification...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to fixing the data or restoring a back-up, you should make sure there's an Uninterruptible Power Supply for every computer on which your application runs. Then, in the event of a power outage, your customers can shut down gracefully and avoid this kind of problem.